# Get the first img src from a string (PHP)

Tags: php, string, image

I get this stored in a PHP variable as a string:

```
$article-text = '<p><img src="img/1.jpg" class="article-image">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><p><img src="img/2.jpg" class="article-image">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>';
```

I need to get the src of first img, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of a regex this is simple.

```
$articletext = '<p><img src="img/1.jpg" class="article-image">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><p><img src="img/2.jpg" class="article-image">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>';

$matches = [];
$src = '';

if(preg_match('/src="(.*?)"/', $articletext, $matches)) {
    $src = $matches[1];
}

echo $src;
```

> img/1.jpg

By the way, variables can **not** include a dash.